# Flink: Temporal Join not emitting data

Tags: apache-flink, flink-sql, flink-table-api

I'm trying to implement a [event-time temporal join](https://nightlies.apache.org/flink/flink-docs-release-1.13/docs/dev/table/sql/queries/joins/#event-time-temporal-join) but I don't see any data being emitted from the join. I don't see any runtime exceptions either.

Flink Version: 1.13

Kafka topics have only 1 partition for now

Here's how I set it up:

I have an "append-only" DataStream (left input/probe side) which looks like the following:

```
{
"eventType": String,
"eventTime": LocalDateTime,
"eventId": String
}
```

So, I convert this datastream to a table before joining them:

```
var eventTable = tableEnv.fromDataStream(eventStream, Schema.newBuilder()
.column("eventId", DataTypes.STRING())
.column("eventTime", DataTypes.TIMESTAMP(3))
.column("eventType", DataTypes.STRING())
.watermark("eventTime", $("eventTime"))
.build());
```

Then, I have the "versioned table" (right input/build side) backed by Kafka (Debezium CDC changelog) which looks like the following:

```
CREATE TABLE metadata (
id                  VARCHAR,
eventMetadata       VARCHAR,
origin_ts           TIMESTAMP(3) METADATA FROM 'value.source.timestamp' VIRTUAL,
PRIMARY KEY (id) NOT ENFORCED,
WATERMARK FOR origin_ts AS origin_ts
) WITH (
'connector'                           = 'kafka',
'properties.bootstrap.servers'        = 'SERVER_ADDR',
'properties.group.id'                 = 'SOME_GROUP',
'topic'                               = 'SOME_TOPIC',
'scan.startup.mode'                   = 'latest-offset',
'value.format'                        = 'debezium-json'
)
```

The join query looks like this:

```
SELECT e.eventId, e.eventTime, e.eventType, m.eventMetadata
FROM events_view AS e
JOIN metadata_view FOR SYSTEM_TIME AS OF e.eventTime AS m
ON e.eventId = m.id
```

Following some other post on here, I've set the source idle-timeout:

```
table.exec.source.idle-timeout -> 5
```

And, I've also tried setting IdlenessTime on the watermarks to make sure source doesn't back emitting the watermarks. At this point I can see watermarks being generated, but I still don't get any results. Everything just ends up sitting on the Temporal Join table.

Comment: can you put toChangelogStream() to both eventTable and metaData tables and watch if they produce any output?

Comment: I did use toChangelogStream() to the join already. However I was able to get it to work by registering a temporal join function and doing a lateral join on it!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, the problem here was the syntax of the processing time temporal join. Here's how to fix this:

```
// register the metadata table as a temporal table func by specifying its watermark and primary-key attributes
    var metadataHistory = tableEnv.from("metadata")
            .createTemporalTableFunction($("proc_time"), $("id"));

    tableEnv.createTemporarySystemFunction("metadata_view", metadataHistory);

    // sql processing time temporal join
    var temporalJoinResult = tableEnv.sqlQuery("SELECT" +
            " e.eventId, e.eventType, e.eventTime, m.eventMetadata" +
            " FROM events_view AS e," +
            " LATERAL TABLE (metadata_view(t.procTime)) AS m" +
            " WHERE e.eventId = m.id");
```

Here, proc_time on metadata needs to be declared within the table DDL like this,

```
CREATE TABLE metadata (
id VARCHAR,
eventMetadata VARCHAR,
proc_time as PROCTIME(),
PRIMARY KEY (id) NOT ENFORCED
) WITH (
'connector'                           = 'kafka',
'properties.bootstrap.servers'        = 'SERVER_ADDR',
'properties.group.id'                 = 'SOME_GROUP',
'topic'                               = 'SOME_TOPIC',
'scan.startup.mode'                   = 'latest-offset',
'value.format'                        = 'debezium-json'
)
```

and while converting the datastream to table, assign the procTime there for that table as well like this,

```
var eventTable = tableEnv.fromDataStream(eventStream, Schema.newBuilder()
.column("eventId", DataTypes.STRING())
.column("eventTime", DataTypes.TIMESTAMP(3))
.column("eventType", DataTypes.STRING())
.columnByExpression("procTime", "PROCTIME()")
.build());
```